# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) on Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, mariadb, macos-big-sur

I just upgraded to MacOS Big Sur, and I found out I can't login to mysql console with `mysql -u root` (without password).

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I installed MariaDB with brew (`brew install mariadb`)

I checked the mysql daemon, and found following error

```
Xuans-MacBook-Pro:~ xuan$ mysqld
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.8-MariaDB) starting as process 2091 ...
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/var/mysql/Xuans-MacBook-Pro-2.lower-test
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/usr/local/var/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/usr/local/var/mysql/aria_log_control'
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2020-12-21 15:46:27 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Here is the permission of `/usr/local/var/mysql/`

```
drwxr-xr-x  68 xuan  admin  2176 21 Dec 15:48 mysql
```

socket file location

```
Xuans-MacBook-Pro:xuan$ mysqld --help --verbose | grep sock
socket                                                       /tmp/mysql.sock
unix-socket                                                  ON
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The aria related errors are specific to mariadb only, so this question is not applicable to mysql.

Comment: I upgraded to big sur too and I'm facing the same issue, although not with mariaDB. when I try to do rails s puma, this error pops up. `sudo mysql -uroot` throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on a 2018 macbook pro with an i9 running big sur 11.1
I could link to a mysql database with mysql workbench and datagrip no problem but when I tried to access mysql from the terminal i got "can't connect to local MYSQL server through socket."
I dropped back to the /usr/local/mysql/bin and ran ./mysql -u root -p and it connects.
Is this a big sur security issue? MAMP is running. The MYSQL editors act normal. It seems big sur will not allow the socket connect through MAMP.

Answer (score -1):

Login as user root via socket requires that the owner of the socket is root, not any other user, since authentication will performed via unix socket authentication.

so a simple `sudo mysql -uroot` should work.